# How to retrieve last _ID from SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have a "logic" problem when making "inserts" on the SQLite database of my app.

These are my tables.[image]
How should I manage the "need" of retrieving **contact_id** and **photos_id** in order to make the insert into the table **contact_photo**?

I know that I can get the last **_id** generated by SQLite with `SELECT seq from sqlite_sequence where ...`, but this doesn't seem a "professional" solution.

Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

have a look to this [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)

```
long insertOrThrow (String table, 
                String nullColumnHack, 
                ContentValues values)
```

will returns row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred